Verifying consistency of heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation robust SEs with a Monte Carlo Experiment
I'm trying to demonstrate the consistency of the default HAC standard errors given in R's sandwich package via a Monte Carlo experiment. I'm using a linear model defined as $Y = X + \varepsilon$ where $X_i \sim N(1,1)$, $X\perp\varepsilon$,and $\varepsilon \sim N(\mathbf 0, \Sigma)$ where
$ \boldsymbol\Sigma_{ij} = \rho^{|i-j|}$ for some $\rho \in (-1,1)$. If $\hat{\beta}$ is the OLS estimator, we can simplify its asymptotic variance as follows:
$$ \text{Avar}(\hat {\beta}) = \text{E}[X'X]^{-1}X'\Sigma X(X'X)^{-1} = \frac{1}{2n(1-\rho)} - \frac{\rho(1-\rho^n)}{2n^2(1-\rho)^2}.$$
I've verified this math with the following Monte Carlo experiment:
library(mvnfast)
library(tidyverse)
library(sandwich)

set_Sigma_ij <- function(i, j, rho){
  rho^abs(i-j)
}

generate_Sigma <- function(rho, n){
  expand_grid(i = 1:n, j = 1:n) %$% 
    map2_dbl(i, j, \(i,j) set_Sigma_ij(i,j, rho)) %>% 
    matrix(nrow = n) 
}


draw_ols_realization <- function(n, rho){
  eps <- rmvn(
    n = 1, 
    mu = rep(0, n), 
    sigma = generate_Sigma(rho = rho, n = n)
    ) %>% 
    as.numeric()
  X <- rnorm(n = n, mean = 1, sd = 1)
  Y <- X + eps
  lm(Y ~ X - 1) %>% 
    coef()
}

true_avar_ols <- function(n, rho){
  (1/(2*n*(1-rho))) - (rho*(1-rho^n)) / (2*n^2 * (1-rho)^2)
}

numerical_avar_ols <- function(N, n, rho){
  1:N %>% 
    map_dbl(\(t) draw_ols_realization(n, rho)) %>% 
    var()
}

# plug in a few values to confirm (for sufficiently large n)
true_avar_ols(n = 140, rho = 0.8)
numerical_avar_ols(N = 1e4, n = 140, rho = 0.8)

When I go to confirm that the HAC standard errors (or rather the corresponding covariance matrix) are consistently estimating $\text{Avar}(\hat {\beta})$, the results aren't making much sense. Here is my code:
estimate_avar_beta <- function(n, rho, X, Y){
  estimated_model <- lm(Y[1:n] ~ X[1:n] - 1) 
  tibble(
    standard = as.numeric(vcov(estimated_model)),
    HAC = as.numeric(vcovHAC(estimated_model)),
    sample_size = n
  )
}

# Estimate Avar(OLS) for a fixed (Y, X) while letting n grow
estimate_avar_beta_over_n <- function(n_vals, rho){
  eps <- rmvn(
    n = 1, 
    mu = rep(0, max(n_vals)), 
    sigma = generate_Sigma(rho = rho, n = max(n_vals))
  ) %>% 
    as.numeric()
  X <- rnorm(n = max(n_vals), mean = 1, sd = 1)
  Y <- X + eps
  n_vals %>% 
    map_df(\(n) HAC_SEs(n, rho, X, Y))
}

# Now do this N times 
draw_N_estimates_avar_beta_over_n <- function(N, n_vals, rho){
  1:N %>% 
    map_df(\(t) draw_HAC_SEs_over_n(n_vals, rho))
}

results <- draw_N_estimates_avar_beta_over_n(
  N = 1e2, 
  n_vals = (1:10)*100, 
  rho = 0.9
)

The estimates given by vcovHAC don't appear consistent.
Am I doing something wrong here? If so what? Is n = 1000 too modest of a sample size? Is my expression for $\text{Avar}(\hat {\beta})$ incorrect? Am I making a boneheaded mistake that eludes me after staring at this for over an hour? Many thanks in advance!

Updated:: see below
My simulations agree with yours: the HAC estimator from the sandwich (not sandwhich) package underestimates the standard errors in your model, and your analytic formula agrees with the simulation standard error.
The graph shows your analytic formula (in red), four traces of the HAC estimator as $n$ increases from 100 to 1000 (in green), and the ordinary OLS variance estimator (in black).  The purple dots are SEs based on 1000 simulations

The HAC estimator works much better if your $X$ has mean zero rather than 1 (as I initially tried), or if there is an intercept in the model.
Also, if you try weightsLumley instead of the default, the bias decreases (although the variability, especially for small $n$, increases). These weights are shorter-range.

I don't think I've ever tried to fit a model like this with no intercept. I suspect there's something going on due to $\hat\beta$ being correlated with $\bar Y_n/\bar X_n$ -- long-range correlation that the weights can't pick up. But I'm not going to claim I understand it at this point.
Update
The issue is at least partly the automatic bandwidth choice. Here are the weights

Obviously that's too short a bandwidth for this problem.  And we can see that the estimate increases with longer bandwidth
> kernHAC(model)
             x
x 0.0009779565
> kernHAC(model,bw=20)
            x
x 0.002586663
> kernHAC(model,bw=100)
            x
x 0.002345724

That also explains why weightsLumley didn't have the same bias -- it has a much simpler weight choice rule.
The analytic SE
> sqrt(true_avar_ols(1000,0.9))
[1] 0.07039176

vcovHAC with bandwidth=100
> sqrt(mean(r[1,]))
[1] 0.06516405

and the simulation SE
> sd(r[2,])
[1] 0.06897224

The HAC estimator is still a bit small, but now the bias is plausibly the finite-sample centering bias.  In fact, if we estimate that bias using diagnostics=TRUE
attr(,"diagnostics")
attr(,"diagnostics")$bias.correction
[1] 1.137374

attr(,"diagnostics")$df
[1] 10.32688

> sqrt(median(r[1,])*1.137374)
[1] 0.06661472

it's really quite close.
We still have the question of why the automatic bandwidth choice was bad, but that's more plausibly due to the intercept being missing since the bandwidth estimator involves fitting an AR-1 model.

Thomas makes a good point. Why don't you take the mean out of the N(1,1) and view it as intercept that's known. This will result in the same model still with mean zero errors. But, similarly to Thomas, I have no idea if that will help. Achim Zeileis wrote the R package on this material (sandwich). It's been a long time but I remember the vignettes and documentation being really good and plentiful. It will be on cran and it may help. He's got examples etc.

Eὕρηκα. I have found [it], maybe

Thanks Thomas. I don't know what kernHac is doing but that was a nice find, regardless.

Thank you so much for the answer Thomas. Could you elebaroate a bit on how the simplicity of the weights given by weightsLumley reduces the bias in question? The bias remains when appealing to Newey and West's original weights of 1 - l/(L+1) for large values of L, so I'm not sure how to interpret that.

My point was just that there isn't any complicated bandwidth modelling in weightsLumley, so if something went wrong with the bwAndrews bandwidth estimator it would still work.
